Mamba broken after updating ssl. ImportError: cannot dynamically load position-independent executable
I work on a linux server that is running Ubuntu. I have been using miniforge to manage environments with packages for specific tasks. Previously, I was using a global install of anaconda in but removed it from my path (and .bashrc) and deleted my environments associated with it before doing my own install of miniforge.
I installed a package using mamba (mamba install -c conda-forge -c bioconda r-soupx) and it updated openssl from 3.2.1 to 3.3.1. The install ran fine, but when loading R to run the package I got an error for a previously working package.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Signac’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/envs/seurat5.0_decontx/lib/R/library/Rsamtools/libs/Rsamtools.so':
  /home/welison/.conda/envs/decontX_reticulate/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/../../libcrypto.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.3.0' not found (required by /home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/envs/seurat5.0_decontx/lib/./libssl.so.3)

In a new terminal I activated the environment and ran openssl help
based on reading a github help page and poking around. It ran fine. I started poking around directories and tried running openssl help from the directory containing the openssl referenced by the environment, and this gave the following error:
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot dynamically load position-independent executable

Clearing hash didn't work, but running openssl help using a path to the global openssl did. I decided to try rolling back the install and ran conda list --revisions but hit this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 12, in <module>
    import ruamel.yaml as yaml
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.main import *  # NOQA
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.loader import BaseLoader, SafeLoader, Loader, RoundTripLoader  # NOQA
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/loader.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.constructor import (
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 4, in <module>
    import base64
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/base64.py", line 11, in <module>
    import binascii
ImportError: libz.so.1: cannot dynamically load position-independent executable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 15, in <module>
    import ruamel_yaml as yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 36, in main_subshell
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .serialize import yaml_round_trip_load
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/serialize.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: No yaml library available. To proceed, conda install ruamel.yaml

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 109, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(main, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 389, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 20, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 52, in handle_exception
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from http.client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/email/_policybase.py", line 7, in <module>
    from email import header
  File "/home/welison/.conda/envs/mamba/lib/python3.11/email/header.py", line 14, in <module>
    import binascii
ImportError: libz.so.1: cannot dynamically load position-independent executable

Every mamba or conda command leads to an error like this, including activating and deactivating environments and search. This is a new problem for me, but a few other users on this server had a similar issue a month back and never managed to resolve it.
